# Help, white-screen with youtube on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, white-screen

I'm using 64-bit ubuntu 12.04LTS on my laptop a sony vaio e-series dual-booting it alongside windows 8.1... i use google chrome but my problem is that sometimes when i watch youtube videos when i go fullscreen and revert it back the whole screen becomes white, but i can still hear sounds, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Might be an issue with your browser's flash plugin or an extension you have. Please provide more details on what flash plugin you're using (including version information) and any extensions that you might have. Visit `chrome://plugins/` to see said information.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/dnesyos7f/ that's all i have in my plugins

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on a mac (osx high sierra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever it might be worth.
The white screen of death as I call it, is due to Chrome trying to use hardware acceleration.
Go to chrome://settings/ (type it in the address bar) and show advanced settings. Under System, uncheck "use hardware acceleration when available" and then restart.
Good luck.

Comment: I'll be damned, but it worked for me.  Thanks!